# How can we draw tables from c# to MicrosoftWord?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dataset, export-to-word

How can we draw the data table as like table from c# to MicrosoftWord? [image]
i had input the sample image what i need , cooperate sale ,branch 1 and branch are data table

Please provide me a suitable answer for this

```
private void ExportToWord(DataSet Collection)
{       
  object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application objWord;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objDoc;
  objWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
  objWord.Visible = true;
  objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table objTable;
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range wrdRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;

  string strText;
  int tables = Collection.Tables.Count;

   for (int k = 0; k < tables; k++)
   {
     int columns = Collection.Tables[k].Columns.Count;
     int rows = Collection.Tables[k].Rows.Count;
     string[] columnNames = Collection.Tables[k].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                              .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                              .ToArray(); 


      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table objNewTable;

      objNewTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, rows, columns, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
      objNewTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 8;

      objNewTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
      objNewTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
      objNewTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Italic = 1;
      objNewTable.Rows[1].Range.Font.Size = 9;
      for (int l = 0; l < columnNames.Count(); l++)
      {
        objNewTable.Cell(1, l).Range.Text = columnNames[l];//"Item Name";
        //objNewTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Price";
       }


       try
       {             
         // objTable.Borders.Shadow = true;
          objNewTable.Borders.Shadow = true;
        }
       catch
       {
       } 
  }
```

}

By this above code am getting the folowing image
[image]

Comment: i need as the first image format when dataset is export to word from c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void word(DataSet Collection)
{
    Word._Application objApp;
    Word._Document objDoc;
    try
    {
        object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object objEndOfDocFlag = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

        //Start Word and create a new document.
        objApp = new Word.Application();
        objApp.Visible = true;

        objDoc = objApp.Documents.Add(ref objMiss, ref objMiss,
            ref objMiss, ref objMiss);

        int tables = Collection.Tables.Count;

        for (int k = 0; k < tables; k++)
        {                

            int columns = Collection.Tables[k].Columns.Count;
            int rows = Collection.Tables[k].Rows.Count;
            string[] columnNames = Collection.Tables[k].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .ToArray(); 
            //Insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
            Word.Paragraph objPara2; //define paragraph object
            object oRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of the page
            objPara2 = objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng); //add paragraph at end of document
            objPara2.Range.Text = "Test Table Caption"; //add some text in paragraph
            objPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 10; //defind some style
            objPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter(); //insert paragraph
            objPara2.Range.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
            //Insert a n x n table, (table with n row and n column)
            Word.Table objTab1; //create table object
            Word.Range objWordRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of document
            objTab1 = objDoc.Tables.Add(objWordRng, rows+1, columns, ref objMiss, ref objMiss); //add table object in word document
            objTab1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
            int iRow, iCols;
            string strText;

            for (int jk = 1; jk <= columnNames.Count()-1; jk++)
            {
                for (iCols = 0; iCols < columnNames.Count(); iCols++)
                {
                    strText = columnNames[iCols];
                    objTab1.Cell(1, iCols+1).Range.Text = strText; //add some text to cell
                }

                objWordRng.InsertParagraphAfter();
                int rowCol = 0;

                for (iRow = 2; iRow <= rows + 1; iRow++)
                {
                    int cols = 0;                      
                    for (iCols = 1; iCols <= columns; iCols++)
                    {
                        strText = Convert.ToString(Collection.Tables[k].Rows[rowCol][cols]);
                        objTab1.Cell(iRow, iCols).Range.Text = strText;
                        cols++;
                       //add some text to cell
                    }
                    rowCol++;
                }
                objTab1.Rows[1].Range.Font.Bold = 1; //make first row of table BOLD
              //  objTab1.Columns[1].Width = objApp.InchesToPoints(3); //increase first column width

            }
            //Add some text after table
            objWordRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range;
            objWordRng.InsertParagraphAfter(); //put enter in document
            objWordRng.InsertAfter("THIS IS THE SIMPLE WORD DEMO : THANKS YOU.");

            try
            {
                // objTable.Borders.Shadow = true;
                objTab1.Borders.Shadow = true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        object szPath = "test.docx"; //your file gets saved with name 'test.docx'
        objDoc.SaveAs(ref szPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occurred while executing code : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //you can dispose object here
    }
}
```